# Boost.Container `dlmalloc` and `jemalloc`

Tags: boost, jemalloc, boost-container

I've introduced Boost.Container into my project which uses `jemalloc` as default allocator, looks like Boots.Container uses custom allocator which is `dlmalloc` and of course when linking I'm failing on "multiple definition" linkage error since two "XXXalloc" were introduced into object files. Turning the 'jemalloc' off is not an option but I cant find if it is possible to turn off the `dlmalloc` usage. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In reality, Boost Container is 99% header-only.

The documentation lists the DLMalloc extension as an extension: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/container/extended_allocators.html

This means you have apparently opted in to the extended allocator. If that's not what you wanted, you know what to remove.

> A good hint is when you don't need to link Boost Container, as a quick inspection of the symbols exported didn't show me anything I recognize except allocator stuff.

Comment: Actually, I didnt opt in, it feels like by default it is used. Still not sure, the build takes forever but it feels like it has something to do with `USE_DL_PREFIX` define

Comment: Ok, looks like defining `USE_DL_PREFIX` did the trick. Did I get you right, your default build (apparently) has it defined by default? Did you build using `bjam`?

Comment: I never had to link the library to date, and I just checked I DO have to link when using those extended allocator examples. That's opting in! (But do post an answer if `USE_DL_PREFIX` somehow can be used to workaround your issue.)

Comment: Aha! Found it, `monotonic_buffer_resource` is used in the project, so, in this case library must be built and linked. I guess it is quite rare case when the Boost.Container used as not "headers only" library. Dont want to mess with it and check if I can exclude the allocator from the build, I'll just stick to the define.